# How To create an expiration date based off the next effective date

Tags: sql

So I can not use a temp table to accomplish this. Basically I need to create an experation date based off the next effective date available.

So for one proc code i have 10 fee schedules with only effective dates. I tried writing this but its not working because it is giving for some records the same expiration date. I know an order by is needed but i placed it in various places and it still gives me the same issue. Any help is greatly appreciated

```
SELECT a.*, 
       ( CASE 
           WHEN (SELECT TOP 1 b.effectivedate - 1 
                 FROM   ietl_profileprocedure b 
                 WHERE  b.effectivedate > a.effectivedate 
                   AND  a.profilesid = b.profilesid) IS NULL THEN (SELECT 
           Dateadd(mm, Datediff(mm, 0, Getdate()) + 1, -1)) 
           ELSE (SELECT TOP 1 b.effectivedate - 1 
                 FROM   ietl_profileprocedure b 
                 WHERE  b.effectivedate > a.effectivedate 
                   AND  a.profilesid = b.profilesid) 
         END ) AS 'ExpDate' 
FROM   ietl_profileprocedure a 
WHERE  profilesid = '4197' 
  AND  procedurecode = '90685'
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Please provide sample data.

Comment: If you are in sql server, check for `LAG()` or `ROW_NUMBER()`

Comment: ProfileSID ProcedureCode EffectiveDate Amount EXPECTED END DATE
4197 90685 1/1/2014 26.63 6/30/2014
4197 90685 7/1/2014 26.9 9/30/2014
4197 90685 10/1/2014 27.68 12/31/2014
4197 90685 1/1/2015 27.68 3/31/2015
4197 90685 4/1/2015 27.39 4/28/2015
4197 90685 4/29/2015 27.39 6/30/2015
4197 90685 7/1/2015 27.68 9/30/2015
4197 90685 10/1/2015 28.48 12/31/2015
4197 90685 1/1/2016 28.48 3/31/2016
4197 90685 4/1/2016 28.48 4/30/2016
4197 90685 5/1/2016 28.48 6/30/2016
4197 90685 7/1/2016 28.48 9/30/2016
4197 90685 10/1/2016 30.42 12/31/2016
4197 90685 1/1/2017 30.42 3/31/2017

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Juan I looked up lead and lag and was able to come up with the code below to suit my needs! now i can have a date something was posted and find the amount that should have pertained to the ProcedureCode at that time more easily

```
SELECT s.ProfileSID,s.ProcedureCode,s.Amount,cast(s.EffectiveDate as date)     as EffectiveDate ,
cast(isnull(dateadd(day,-1,LEAD(EffectiveDate) OVER (ORDER BY     ProfileSID,ProcedureCode,EffectiveDate
)),getdate())as date) ExpDate
FROM iETL_ProfileProcedure s
WHERE ProfileSID IN ('4197')and ProcedureCode = '90685'
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Few things. Check [THIS](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm) to format your query for easy to read. And if you leave a comment with `@username` the user get a notification. I just saw it for pure luck. And when adding the data dont leave it as comment because isnt readeable. Just edit your question with the aditional info.

Comment: and you probably only need `OVER (ORDER BY effectivedate)`